# Can I extend the schema for my openldap server to store MCX records?

Tags: mac-osx, ldap, openldap, osx-snow-leopard, mcx

I'm beginning to deprecate my Apple XServers and thus MacOSX Server as well. I'm currently using AD for my authentication and authorization, and my Mac OS X Server box to hold the MCX records for the Mac clients.

Can I extend the schema in OpenLDAP on Ubuntu server to hold my MCX records? Perhaps I could grab the schemas from my MacOSX box and load them in...?

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest having a look at [Apple´s Open Directory Documentation](http://images.apple.com/server/macosx/docs/Open_Directory_Admin_v10.6.pdf) and either import the Apple Extended Schema into your OpenLDAP (which should take care of all the record mappings) or manually map Apple´s custom ldap-style attributes (eg. apple-user) to the correct OD/AD class (eg. Users). Also have a look at [this mini-tutorial](http://www.emmes-world.de/mac-afp-homes.html).